# What happens when we try to set the register of the currently executing code?

Tags: assembly, real-mode

CodeProject has [an article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45788/The-Real-Protected-Long-mode-assembly-tutorial-for):

> CS always holds the segment of the currently executing code. You
>   cannot set CS by using, say, mov cs,ax. When you call a function that
>   resides in another segment (FAR call), or when you jump to another
>   segment (FAR jump), CS changes.

So what happens when we try to modify the register directly by using `mov cs, ax`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Intel manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), you get an "undefined opcode" exception:

> ### `mov` — Move
>
> #### { Protected Mode, Real-Address Mode, Virtual-8086 Mode, 64-Bit Mode} Excpetions
>
> #UD If attempt is made to load the `CS` register.

Comment: Assuming the assembler will even allow you to assemble the instruction.

Comment: Bah, @KerrekSB, real men use toggle switches to input binary when they need something reprogrammable.  Otherwise they build their own dedicated computation circuits out of spare parts.  ;-)

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: Naturally :-)